# How to show ApplicationName(Not Responding) in title bar for borderless window application

Tags: c#, wpf, borderless

I've a borderless wpf application. When the application is not responding. the application title bar will show like ApplicationName(Not Responding).

[image]

This is applicable for bordered application (with title bar). For my case, my title bar is just a label control with text. So, how can I detect the application is not responding and display the title as ApplicationName(Not Responding)? Is it dealing with [Process.Responding Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Fix the application to be more responsive,  don't work around other issues.

Answer (score 2):

That is something the system normally handles itself.  Of course, as you've seen, not having a title bar means the system can't exactly do it.

If the app is truly not responding, then you can't change it's window title.  Because, well, *it's not responding* and therefore won't *respond* to commands.

If the app is responding, then you shouldn't confuse the user by displaying a message which is wholly inaccurate.

A better path would be to separate any type of long running processing that is causing the app to freeze up into it's own thread while leaving the UI responsive.